# How to implement alpha gradient on a image?

Tags: iphone, ios, gradient, alpha, quartz-2d

I want to implement alpha gradient on an image. From 0.5 alfa on top of the image to 0.0 on bottom.
Any advice, tutorial, link is welcome.

Comment: do you want to modify the original image or do you you only care that it's displayed with a gradient?

Comment: I only want do display an gradient under the image.

Comment: Anomie has covered this case in his answer

Comment: In the case that I both want to display the image and then save a modified copy?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `CGImageCreateWithMask` to apply a masking image to it. You could generate an appropriate mask simply enough by drawing to a greyscale or alpha-only CGBitmapContext with `CGContextDrawLinearGradient`.

If it's being displayed as the content of a CALayer, you could apply an appropriate masking layer to the parent layer's `mask` property. You could use a `CAGradientLayer` with appropriate colors to create this mask.

You can draw the image to a CGBitmapContext, and then draw an appropriate alpha gradient over it using `kCGBlendModeDestinationIn`. Or draw the gradient first, and draw the image over it using `kCGBlendModeSourceIn`. In both cases, `CGContextDrawLinearGradient` is again your friend. Then, of course, get the image out of the CGContext using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` or `CGImageCreate` on the underlying data buffer.

Or, of course, if you control the original image and never need a version without the alpha gradient, you could just store it as a PNG with the appropriate alpha values in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [`CAGradientLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradient.frame = view.bounds;
 gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
 [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

**Another option**

Try the answer suggested by [@Caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643383/caleb) in this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617113/how-to-render-a-radial-gradient-onto-a-new-uiimage-on-an-iphone)

> You can go for [Graphics Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101).
>   All drawing happens in a graphics
>   context. If you want to create an
>   image that has a radial gradient, or a
>   linear gradient, or anything else,
>   you'll need to:
>
> - Create a graphics context for your    image with
>     `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.
> - Do whatever drawing you want to    appear in the image.
> - Call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`
>     to get the image from the context.
>     This gives you a `UIImage`, so no need
>     to convert from a `CGImage`.
> - Call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` to    clean up the context.
>
> You can also have a look at [Radial
>   gradient on UImage](http://splinter.com.au/rendering-a-radial-gradient-on-the-iphone-obj)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new image by reading the pixels in the existing image (getting their RGBA) line by line adding them to the new image with the same RGB values but adjusting the alpha values on a per line basis.

Some other SO questions that should give you everything you'd need for that:

[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

[Can I edit the pixels of the UIImage's property CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281210/can-i-edit-the-pixels-of-the-uiimages-property-cgimage)

Comment: While this will work, it will probably be much slower than using Core Graphics. Don't forget you will also have to adjust the RGB values if you are using premultiplied alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I found something [here](http://codingangry.com/index.php/site/article/ios_gradent_with_transparency/),
it works great!

```
AlphaGradientView* gradient = [[AlphaGradientView alloc] initWithFrame:
                           CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 150, 0, 150, 
                                                self.view.frame.size.height)];

gradient.color = [UIColor yellowColor];
gradient.direction = GRADIENT_RIGHT;
[self.view addSubview:gradient];
```