# iOS: Gradient transparency on image

Tags: iphone, ios, gradient, cgcontext

Im trying to figure out if its possible in a Graphic Context to draw an image like:
[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, it's been quite a while since I've done it however and can't find my own example of how it's done. I used apple's The Elements sample code as my starting point, they do the gradient fade on the detail views of each element. Sample code available here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This answer seems to be exactly what you need: [How to implement alpha gradient on a image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908731/how-to-implement-alpha-gradient-on-a-image?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks guys, i think my question is solved. If you want, copy your comment to an answer. I'll mark the first one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement alpha gradient on a image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908731/how-to-implement-alpha-gradient-on-a-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer seems to be exactly what you need: [How to implement alpha gradient on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908731/how-to-implement-alpha-gradient-on-a-image?rq=1)