# Overlapping UIImage with another image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement alpha gradient on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908731/how-to-implement-alpha-gradient-on-a-image)

I have 2 images below

[image] [image]

With these 2 images I want to create following effect. Any technique you think to mask these images to create required effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gradient mask to create something like this, but you wouldn't get the gloss and shadows that you see in your final image:

[image]

Comment: can you plz show some sample code?