# Implement a radial alpha gradient on a CALayer or CGImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, calayer, core-image

Is it possible to create a radial alpha gradiant on a `CALayer`, `CGImage`, or `CIImage`? How would one go about implementing this the simplest and quickest way?

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, I'd like to fade the edges of a cropped oval image I've cut out using the `CIImage` crop filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617113/how-to-render-a-radial-gradient-onto-a-new-uiimage-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the appropriate alpha channel by :

1) use the same oval shape as you already used on your picture.
2) apply a very strong (=large radius) CIGaussianBlur filter on your Alpha channel, to make the edges smooth.