# macOS Use CGContextRef and always black

Tags: macos, core-graphics, nsbezierpath

I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188058/how-to-draw-a-circle-path-with-color-gradient-stroke#) solution to build a gradient circle by @Johnny Rockex on macOS.But I got some problems.

In the  @Johnny Rockex original answer

> //3.1 setup

```
UIBezierPath * bezierPath;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(dimension/2, dimension/2);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(dimension, dimension), true, 0.0);
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, dimension, dimension));
```

this method is provided by UIKit rather than AppKit. So I use some methods by AppKit

```
NSImage *contentView  =[[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(dimension, dimension)];

[contentView lockFocus];
[NSGraphicsContext currentContext].imageInterpolation = NSImageInterpolationNone;
CGContextRef gc = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]CGContext];
NSRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, dimension, dimension));

//fill Colors in bazierPath
for (int n = 0; n<numberOfColors;n++) {
   ...
}


[contentView unlockFocus];
[radialGradient setImage:contentView];
```

Unfortunately, I got a weird result at last[image]
 [image]

My colors array and bazierPath is correct but only a little part of the image has color. 
Maybe is not caused by the title despection but I can not find any clue in other parts of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike UIBezierPath, [appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbezierpath/1520659-appendbezierpathwitharcwithcente?language=objc) is measured in degrees.

Comment: Yes, I found it and fixed this problem. Thanks